# Matching the string after the last equation mark to key1 in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to append directory name to filename for select filetypes and camera models based on a dictionary.

The files are stored in a directory with the following pattern. Directory names always end with `=` mark followed by `key1`:

```
0001=d5                             #d5 is an ID for the camera model
 DSCN001                            #dir name needs to be appended to filenames below
    [media files]
0002=blahblahblah=alpha9            #alpha9 is an ID for the camera model
  SONYDATA                             
    STREAM001                       #dir name needs to be appended to filenams below
      [media files]
```

The code below recognized the last 2 characters of the directory that specifies the camera model and matches against `key1` in the dictionary table. In case of `alpha9` it does not work because `alpha9` is longer than 2 characters.

**Q**: How can I  change the code, so instead it **recognizes any string after the last equation** `=` mark in the directory's name and matches that against `key1`?

Code:

```
config = {
    'd5': {},
    'alpha9': {},
}
config['d5']['append_dir_to_file'] = 1
config['d5']['append_dir_for'] = ('nef', 'NEF', 'jpg', 'JPG')
config['alpha9']['append_dir_to_file'] = 1
config['alpha9']['append_dir_for'] = ('mp4', 'MP4')

folder_keys = config.keys()
target = os.getcwd() 

def sb_travel(dirs, flag=False, target=False, k=False):
    for p1 in dirs:
        if not flag and p1[-2:] in folder_keys:
            main =  next(os.walk("%s/%s"%(target,p1)))[1]
            sb_travel(main, True, "%s/%s"%(target,p1), p1[-2:])
        if flag:
            dirslist = next(os.walk("%s/%s"%(target,p1)))
            main =  dirslist[1] 
            if config[k]['append_dir_to_file']: 
                for f in dirslist[2]: 
                    ext = f.split('.')[1] if len(f.split('.')) > 1 else False
                    if ext and ext in config[k]['append_dir_for']:
                        old_file = "%s/%s/%s"%(target,p1,f)        
                        new_file = "%s/%s/%s_%s"% (target,p1,p1,f) 
                        os.rename(old_file, new_file)              
            sb_travel(main, True, "%s/%s"%(target,p1),k)    
if not os.path.exists(target):
    print ("Invalid Directory Location")
main =  next(os.walk(target))[1]
sb_travel(main, False, target)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `p1.split('=')[-1] in folder_keys`

This matches the whole string if there is no equation mark, so you might want to check that first with `'=' in p1`

**edit:** Given input `dirs = ['0001=d5', '0002=alpha9']` my code:

```
for p1 in dirs:
    print(p1.split('=')[-1])
```

gives output:

```
d5
alpha9
```

Which is what you asked for originally. I won't help you debug your script.

Comment: there are either 1 or 2 equation marks in the dir name and the program checks that way before. now i need to recognize the string **after the last** equation mark (so it does not matter if there is 1 or 2 of them). testing your code now.

Comment: `if not flag and p1.split('=')[-1] in folder_keys:` no luck, does not append now for any files. no error msg.

Comment: There seems to be another `p1[-2:]` inside the if clause when you call sb_travel. You have to substitute that too.

Comment: tried with `if not flag and p1.split('=')[-1] in folder_keys:` and `sb_travel(main, True, "%s/%s"%(target,p1), p1.split('=')[-1] in folder_keys)`.  No append of dir names. Error: `in <module>
    sb_travel(main, False, target)
in sb_travel
---AND---    sb_travel(main, True, "%s/%s"%(target,p1), p1.split('=')[-1] in folder_keys)
---AND---in sb_travel
    if config[k]['append_dir_to_file']: KeyError: True`

Comment: remove the `in folder_keys` from the latter substitution. And maybe add some crude debugging like `print(p1.split('=')[-1])` to help you determine what's going on

Comment: i tried. no errror, nor rename. `sb_travel(main, True, "%s/%s"%(target,p1), p1.split('=')[-1])`

Comment: gives every subdirs within the ...`=d5` and ...`=alpha9`: `125NCD3S
126NCD5
127NCD5
DCIM
112___09
112___10
112___11
CANONMSC
DCIM
AVF_INFO
101MSDCF
DCIM
CLIPINF
PLAYLIST
STREAM
BDMV
AVCHD
SONY
PRIVATE`